# Display range when user clicks or enter textbox and validate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-applications

How to display a popup with a textbox range when the user tabs into the textbox or clicks it and validate it if the user enters a non-range value in asp.net? Currently i'm using js and css to display a panel using z-index, but no validation. Is there a better way?

I tried the Ajax Validator controls but it seems they only popup when the user leaves the textbox. And also, the textbox's are dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

If the range for the textbox is fixed you have to use only javascript. Incase you need validation for dynamic content you must call web methods or webservices using ajax.
The Markup will be like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
  EnablePageMethods="true" />
<script language="javascript">
 function UpdateTime() {
   PageMethods.GetCurrentDate(OnSucceeded, OnFailed); 
 }

 function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
   $get('Label1').innerHTML = result; 
 }

 function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
   $get('Label1').innerHTML = "An error occured.";
 }
</script>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Update Me!" /><br />
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Web Method Update" 
  onclick="UpdateTime();" />
```

You must enable the page methods of the script manager and call the method written in page back as PageMethods.YourMethodName(JavascriptMethodIfCallingSuccess,JavascriptMethodOnError);
You can write the page back code in c# as below

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentDate()
{
  return DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
}
```

Now you will get the return value from server in your javascript. Don't use this method if your validation is always fixed and if server side validation not required. It may cause unwanted load for your page and server.